# ES6 and variable scope inside a promise

Tags: promise, ecmascript-6, aurelia, deployd

Not sure what I'm missing here.

I need to get the output of `data` into `this.contact`. Right now, I'm using a static class variable, but it seems dirty to have to do that.

```
export class contactEdit {
  static t; // static class var
  constructor() {
    this.id = null;
    this.contact = null;
    contactEdit.t = this;
  }

  activate(id) {
    this.id = id;
    let contact = this.contact; // scoped version of class var
    return dpd.contacts.get(id).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      contactEdit.t.contact = data; // this works
      contact = data; // this doesn't
    });
  }
}
```

Normally I would create a `var contact` inside the `activate()` function (it works in the Chrome console) but this doesn't seem to working in ES6.

Chrome console:

```
var c = null;
undefined
c;
null
dpd.contacts.get('a415fdc8f5a7184d').then(function(data) {
      c = data;
    });
Object {}fail: (n)then: (e,t)__proto__: Object
c;
Object {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", id: "a415fdc8f5a7184d"}
```

Comment: Did you not just want `this.contact = data;` instead of `contact = data;`?

Comment: `static t;` is not ES6. Are you using typescript or something?

Comment: You should not store promise results as instance properties anyway. Store the promise if you need to.

Comment: @trincot no, `this` inside the promise no longer refers to the class. That was my first attempt :)

Comment: @Bergi, not typescript. Some experimental features turned on though.

Comment: @Bergi Aurelia needs a property to bind to. The `activate` method returns a promise so that the screen waits for the data before loading. Once loaded, the binding needs a property. Or so I understand it thus far.

Comment: @agrothe: OK it always depends on how you are using the property of course. If Aurelia cannot render promises directly, you might need it, but always keep in mind that it might be `undefined` when the promise is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to do two things. First, use an arrow function, and second, use `this.contact = data;

```
activate(id) {
  this.id = id;
  return dpd.contacts.get(id).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.contact = data;
  });
}
```

You use an arrow function because it deals with JavaScript's "`this`" issue, where this refers to the lexical scope of the function, and not the object you're currently in. Using an arrow function makes sure that `this` outside the arrow function is the same as `this` inside the arrow function.

You need to use `this.contact` because `contact` is an instance property of the class.

Comment: best answer on all of stack overflow today

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis I Agree, the arrow function does the trick.

Comment: @AshleyGrant, perhaps you could add a sentence or two on why the arrow function fixes this? I'm going to go read up on this but would help others I'm sure.

Comment: For others interested in the details, see the Lexical This section from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `contact = data;` will update the value of the local `contact` variable, but will not change the value of the `this.contact`.
You need to update the `contact` contact property instead. The problem is that you do not have access to `this` inside the body of your anonymous function (or rather, the `this` of the anonymous function is not going to be the same `this` as `activate`'s).

There is different ways to solve this.

1- You can save activate's context (`this`) into a variable in the closure of `activate` so that you can access it inside the core of `then`.

```
activate(id) {
    this.id = id;
    let that = this;
    return dpd.contacts.get(id).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      that.contact = data;
    });
  }
```

2- You can bind the function to `activate`'s `this` so that it is called with the same context.

```
activate(id) {
    this.id = id;
    return dpd.contacts.get(id).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      this.contact = data;
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

3- (recommended with ES6) you can use an arrow function (arrow functions do not have their own context, so they preserve the one where they are created)

```
activate(id) {
    this.id = id;
    return dpd.contacts.get(id).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.contact = data;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I had already tried #1 with no luck. Going to try #2 though to see how that works. #3 works.

Comment: #1 and #2 also work. My error was using `let contact = this.contact`. Apparently that won't work where as `let that = this` does work. Odd, but I'll take it.

Comment: This is not odd. If you do `contact = something`, you are assigning a new value to the `contact` **variable**. You are not modifying the previous value that were assigned to it. What you are trying to do is to change the `contact` property of the `this` object. This property is unrelated to the `contact` variable (apart from the fact that you initialise its value to the value pointed by `this.contact`). The only way to change the value pointed by the property `prop` of an object `obj` is by writing something similar to `obj.prop = something`.